# parameter gets zero in subreport crystal report

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, report, subreport

Can anyone help me in this issue

I am using Crystal report,and visual studio for development

In crystal report, The parameter passed from the main report gets zero in subreport. I have displayed both the passed field and the parameter in the report. The field shows a value **744** while the parameter shows **0.00**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i suppose you use a subreport link to pass the parameter, is it correct? may you tell the options you use? (fields to link to, subreport parameter field, select data in subreport...)

Comment: Instead of parameter you can use `Shared Variable`..